# Unable to add item on eBay API due to Item Specific Type missing

Tags: ebay-api, ebay-sdk, ebay-lms

We are getting the following error when calling the eBay `AddItemRequest` API

**The item specific Type is missing. Add Type to this listing, enter a valid value, and then try again.21919303**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AddItemRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
  <RequesterCredentials>
    <eBayAuthToken>XXXXXXXXXXX</eBayAuthToken>
  </RequesterCredentials>
  <ErrorLanguage>en_US</ErrorLanguage>
  <WarningLevel>High</WarningLevel>
  <Item>
    <Title>test-800</Title>
    <Description>test 800</Description>
    <PrimaryCategory>
      <CategoryID>176971</CategoryID>
    </PrimaryCategory>
    <StartPrice>200</StartPrice>
    <CategoryMappingAllowed>true</CategoryMappingAllowed>
    <ConditionID>1000</ConditionID>
    <Country>US</Country>
    <Currency>USD</Currency>
    <DispatchTimeMax>3</DispatchTimeMax>
    <ListingDuration>GTC</ListingDuration>
    <ListingType>FixedPriceItem</ListingType>
    <PictureDetails>
      <GalleryType>Gallery</GalleryType>
      <PictureURL>https://eznetcrm.net/img/eZnetLogo.png</PictureURL>
    </PictureDetails>
    <PostalCode>32746</PostalCode>
    <ProductListingDetails>
      <UPC></UPC>
      <BrandMPN>
        <Brand>HP</Brand>
        <MPN>845418-B21</MPN>
      </BrandMPN>
      <IncludeStockPhotoURL>true</IncludeStockPhotoURL>
      <IncludePrefilledItemInformation>true</IncludePrefilledItemInformation>
      <UseFirstProduct>true</UseFirstProduct>
      <UseStockPhotoURLAsGallery>true</UseStockPhotoURLAsGallery>
      <ReturnSearchResultOnDuplicates>true</ReturnSearchResultOnDuplicates>
    </ProductListingDetails>
    <Quantity>5</Quantity>
    <ItemSpecifics>
      <NameValueList>
<Name>Brand</Name>
<Value>HP</Value>
  </NameValueList>
  <NameValueList>
<Name>MPN</Name>
<Value>845418-B21</Value>
  </NameValueList>
    </ItemSpecifics>
    <ReturnPolicy>
      <ReturnsAcceptedOption>ReturnsAccepted</ReturnsAcceptedOption>
      <RefundOption>MoneyBack</RefundOption>
      <ReturnsWithinOption>Days_30</ReturnsWithinOption>
      <ShippingCostPaidByOption>Buyer</ShippingCostPaidByOption>
    </ReturnPolicy>
    <ShippingDetails>
      <ShippingType>Flat</ShippingType>
      <ShippingServiceOptions>
        <ShippingServicePriority>1</ShippingServicePriority>
        <ShippingService>USPSMedia</ShippingService>
       <ShippingServiceAdditionalCost>0</ShippingServiceAdditionalCost>
        <ShippingServiceCost>0</ShippingServiceCost>
      </ShippingServiceOptions>
    </ShippingDetails>
    <Site>US</Site>
  </Item>
</AddItemRequest>
```

We are trying to add an item using the above XML through eBay APIs but are unable to do so. What we are doing wrong in XML format? Also, we have added specific data as we got an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When adding `ItemSpecifics`, you will need to check if there are any `ItemSpecific` entries that are mandatory for your `CategoryID`. This can be checked from the [GetCategorySpecifics](https://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/reference/ebay/GetCategorySpecifics.html) API.

In your case, the category ID is `176971` and in the XML payload, there are two existing `ItemSpecifics`: `Brand` and `MPN`. As suggested by the error message you are getting and confirming from the `GetCategorySpecifics` API on eBay, it is evident that you need to add an ItemSpecific with the name **`Type`** within your ItemSpecifics. After doing that, your `ItemSpecifics` should look like this:

```xml
  <ItemSpecifics>
     <NameValueList>
        <Name>Brand</Name>
        <Value>HP</Value>
     </NameValueList>

     <NameValueList>
        <Name>Type</Name>
        <Value>CustomTypeNameHere</Value>
     </NameValueList>

     <NameValueList>
        <Name>MPN</Name>
        <Value>845418-B21</Value>
     </NameValueList>
  </ItemSpecifics>
```

You can verify the call using the `VerifyAddItemResponse` API once you add the `Type` ItemSpecific.

In general, to figure out what ItemSpecifics are needed for a given `CategoryId`, you can refer to the following documentation ([Listing with Required Item Specifics](https://developer.ebay.com/devzone/guides/features-guide/content/development/ItemSpecifics-Advanced.html#ListingwithRequiredItemSpecifics). However, very briefly, to determine which item specifics are required, call `GetCategorySpecifics` to retrieve the item specifics recommendations for the category you're listing in. In the response, look for these fields for each recommendation:

- This item specific name is required for the category: `Recommendations.NameRecommendation.ValidationRules.MinValues`
- You can only use one of these values that eBay has defined (as returned in the response): `Recommendations.NameRecommendation.ValidationRules.SelectionMode=SelectionOnly`

Comment: Seems this call is deprecated now.  Any way to check GetCategorySpecifics now?